# Update failed with hasManyThrough relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to update child model with Laravel hasManyThough.

#### What I've tried

The Base model has the relationship like below:

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Transaction', 'App\Invoice');
}
```

and I use below code to update child items.

```
$order->transactions()->update([
        'customer_id' => 100,
        'user_id'     => 100
    ]);
```

#### What I'm getting

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'customer_id' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: update `invoice_items` inner join `invoices` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoice_items`.`invoice_id` set `customer_id` = 2, `user_id` = 2, `updated_at` = 2018-09-21 22:03:45 where `invoices`.`order_id` = 1)
```

I'm using laravel 5.6 and the model is default as `artisan make:model` provide.

#### Update:

Table structure

```
orders
- id
- user_id
- customer_id
- content
invoices
- id
- order_id
- user_id
- customer_id
- content
transactions
- id
- invoice_id
- user_id
- customer_id
- content
```

Comment: The problem is with your query which you used here. Share the same for more clarification.

Comment: Do you think I need to change the column name for one table?

Comment: I suggest updating the `Transaction` model directly.

Comment: I can't because The order have many invoices and invoices have many transactions.

Comment: if you call $order->transactions do you get a collection of transactions?

Comment: Yes, I can see the transactions collections on the order.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I made a temp solution for this issue.

```
foreach ($order->transactions as $transaction) {
        $transaction->update($updateRules);
    }
```

Please feel free to post your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution:

Column 'customer_id' in field list is ambiguous,i.e. customer_id field exists in both the tables using for inner join. Use customer_id with table name using Dot (.) operator.

update `invoice_items` inner join `invoices` on `invoices`.`id` = `invoice_items`.`invoice_id` set   invoices. `customer_id` = 2,   invoices.`user_id` = 2, `updated_at` = 2018-09-21 22:03:45 where `invoices`.`order_id` = 1)

Comment: This is not a solution exactly.

Comment: Earlier table schema was not present in the question. Now I have updated my answer.